# Julia keeps trying to access files on my mapped network drive

Tags: windows-7, julia

[image]

I had a network drive mapped to U:
Even if I reinstall Julia after disconnecting the network drive, the issue persists. How can I remove all previous configuration from prev julia install.

Update: `homedir()` returns "U:\". How can I change it to point to my user directory ?  Looks like some config files are not cleaned up by windows uninstall because when I installed now, I had no drive name U:

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see where the tool searches for config files.

Comment: Seems like it is working now properly. `homedir()` gives my user directory. Dont know what the problem is though. Any does anyone know how to change the directory returned by `homedir()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an Environment variable `HOME` which pionts to the correct home directory `C:\Users\username` solves the issue.

Comment: nice to see that you found the cause